# Registry changes while changing 'Sort By' settings in windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

I have requirement of selecting the 'Sort by' type of Windows Explorer using command. But I didnt get any commands. So I think I can do changes in registry.

But I didnt get the registry changes while changing the Sort type of Windows explorer.
[image]

In which registry keys I need to do changes in order to select 'Sort by' types like 'Date Modified', 'Type', 'Size', etc.

Please  help.

Comment: I believe it can't be done manually, as the sort order are stored as REG-BINARY and the folder view "Bag" slot is dynamic. But a shell programmer could do this with with the necessary APIs MS has on the folder views stuff. May be someone else has a solution using AutoHotKey or something similar. https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/55793-sort-by-date-modified-folder-view/

Comment: use RegFrom App to trace which data are  changed: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html